# What is this mark (-) called?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, names

Address:
#FloorUnit - #UnitNumber

Example:
#123 - #123

What is standard name of the "-" in between FloorUnit and UnitNumber? Make sense.

Comment: You mean the ***hyphen***? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hyphen

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by #FloorUnit and #UnitNumber. They seem to mean the same thing, and your example gives #123 in both cases, which doesn't help with clarity.

Comment: There are at least a half-dozen different terms that might be used, depending on the context.

Comment: @Josh61 No, this is a dash, not a hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it is called a dash however if you were to use it in a sentence you might use the word 'to' or 'through' in its place but it all depends on context.

Example: "Apartment #100 - #102'

might be read as 'Apartment number 100 to number 102'

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Apartment number***s***" (plural) if you are referring to 3 of them?

Comment: Does it sound right to say Apartment numbers 100 to apartment numbers 102?  No.  If I hadn't declared the second number then yes.

Comment: Sorry! I mis-read it.  I should have suggested "Apartment***s*** number 100 to number 102".

Comment: This has a definitive answer provided by best practices in Typography.